# How do I make a Bootstrap navbar responsive in Angular?

Tags: html, angular, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm currently creating a responsive Bootstrap navbar in Angular. I'm using Bootstrap v3.

However, the toggle navigation doesn't open in a mobile view and the "Manage" dropdown isn't working.

app.component.html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <app-header></app-header>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

header.component.html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Recipe Book</a>
      </div>
  
      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Recipes <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Shopping Lists</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Manage <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Save Data</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Fetch Data</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
```

Comment: There are a lot of examples already available on the bootstrap site how to make responsive navbar, you can have a look here along with the version number: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could include a small test project showing the problem, for example on [stackblitz](https://www.stackblitz.com)

Comment: app.component try to use `container-fluid` instead off `container`